# Equivalence Relationship in Compact Space

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $X$ is compact space and that $\thicksim$ is an equivalence relation on $X$.  I want to prove $X /\thicksim$, in the quotient topology, is a compact space.

Comment: Do you know the theorem stating that the continuous image of a compact space is compact?

Comment: Any open cover of $X/\sim$ yields an open cover of $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p:X\to X /\thicksim$ the quotient map.Let {$V_i:i\in I$} be an open cover of $X /\thicksim$. Then for every $i\in I$ ,$p^{-1}(V_i)$ is open and $X=\cup_{i\in I} p^{-1}(V_i)$.  Because $X$ is compact there are $i_1,i_2,...,i_n\in I:X=\cup_{j=1}^{n} p^{-1}(V_j)=>X/\thicksim=p(X)=\cup_{j=1}^{n} V_j$.